# How to convert a variable value on the fly in Ansible/Jinja2 template?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I need to set a properties in two different files through Ansible/Jinja2 template file. In one of the files the values should be comma-separated, in the other space-separated.

Currently I use two different variables:

```
values_space_separated = value1 value2 value3
values_comma_separated = value1,value2,value3
```

How can I avoid duplication?

Is there a way to convert a value of the variable on-the-fly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always use the [`regex_replace`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#other-useful-filters) filter.

So if you normally define the variable as:

```
values = value1,value2,value3
```

Then if you need it space separated instead then you could always just do this:

```
{{ values | regex_replace(',',' ') }}
```